# Why can't we take the reciprocal of a stochastic parameter?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, noise

I was told recently that we can't (or shouldn't) take the reciprocal of a stochastic parameter with white noise. Specifically, if we have a stochastic parameter $\lambda_t$
$$
\lambda_t = \lambda_0 + \delta W_t
$$
where $\lambda_0 \ne 0$ is fixed and $\delta W_t$ is white noise (Wiener increment) with $|\delta W_t| \ll |\lambda_0$|, then we shouldn't ever write $1/\lambda_t$.

Why is this the case? What 'breaks' when we try to take the inverse of white noise? A related question is whether $1/\delta W_t$ is a meaningful quantity at all or simply undefined.

Comment: Your equation does not make sense given that there's a differential wihtout an integral and other terms are not differentials. Also, who told you that you cannot write $1/\lambda_t$? I thought you just wrote it, so apparently you can.

Comment: I've edited the notation from 'dWt' to 'delta Wt' to be clearer on what I mean. I'm talking about a small change in the value of the parameter that is sampled from white noise. I'm not sure exactly what the correct notation would be.

Comment: @SBF I was told that I shouldn't (not can't) write 1/λ, as in it doesn't make sense and should be avoided in calculations. My question is regarding why.

Comment: Don’t see a reason why can’t you write either reciprocal.

Comment: In particular, $1/\delta W_t$ if this means $1/(W_{t+\delta t} - W_t)$ is just a random variable with a certain distribution. So is $1/lambda_t$. At the same time $1/\mathrm dW_t$ does not seem to have any formal meaning, but neither does expression $\lambda_t = \lambda_0 + \mathrm dW_t$ at least for $W_t$ being the Brownian motion. You can have different amount of $\mathrm d$ on rhs and lhs when you tackle differential forms.